# Discord.js Embed Gifs

Tags: discord, discord.js, embed, gif

**I'm trying to make my bot choose a random gif, and I can't understand why the gif doesn't load, the embed is sent as it should but the gif keeps loading infinitely**

```js
    const list = require('./list.json');
    module.exports = {
        name: 'soco',
        aliases: ['sc'],
        utilisation: '{prefix}soco',
            async execute(client, message, args) {
                
                var user = message.mentions.members.first();
                if(!user) return;
                var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
                var colors = [
                    0xffffff,
                    0x000000,
                    0x0000ff,
                    0xff0000,
                    0x7a7a7a,
                    0x00ffff,
                    0xffd700,
                    0x4b0082
                ]
                var randomgif = list[Math.floor(Math.random()* list.length)]
                
                    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setDescription(`${message.author} DEU UM SOCÃO EM ${user}`)
                    .setColor(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)])
                    .setImage(randomgif)
                    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]})
    
            },
        };
```

List.json

```json
        [
        "https://tenor.com/view/anime-punch-knockout-wasted-smack-gif-11451829",
        "https://tenor.com/view/punch-fight-anime-girl-rage-gif-15865733",
        "https://tenor.com/view/slap-handa-seishuu-naru-kotoishi-barakamon-anime-barakamon-gif-5509136",
        "https://tenor.com/view/anime-blush-shy-blushing-girl-gif-21835529",
        "https://tenor.com/view/tgggg-anime-punch-gif-13142581",
        "https://tenor.com/view/some-guy-getting-punch-anime-punching-some-guy-anime-anime-punch-punch-anime-gif-22671439",
        "https://tenor.com/view/anime-smash-lesbian-punch-wall-gif-4790446",
        "https://tenor.com/view/saki-saki-kanojo-mo-kanojo-kmk-saki-anime-gif-22206764",
        "https://tenor.com/view/rin243109-blue-exorcist-anime-punch-gif-13785833",
        "https://tenor.com/view/loli-shomin-sample-loliangry-kawai-gif-21035026",
        "https://tenor.com/bf6G3.gif",
        "https://tenor.com/bbJtm.gif"
    ]
```

PrintScreen
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU9QH.png

Comment: Only the last two items are images in your `list`. The other ones are HTML pages that can't be used with `.setImage`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because about all of the links are not `gif` links. They're links directing to tenor.com website and will show you (yes the gif) but also the footer, the sign up button, other gifs that are related etc.. For each individual link (except the last two since they do end in .gif)

1. Go to the website (copy/paste the link)
2. Right click the image and select "copy link"

[image: Copy link]

3. Replace the link in your .json file with the new copied link !
   (for example if the original link was `https://tenor.com/view/anime-punch-knockout-wasted-smack-gif-11451829`, replace it with `https://tenor.com/Wdi5.gif`)
4. Do the same thing for all the links ! And make sure that at the end all of the links end in `.gif`